# Replace spaces with comma but not in the whole line

Tags: text-processing, sed

```
some name;another thing; random; value value value value value
```

I'm trying to replace the spaces that occur after the `random;` using sed. It's important to keep the spaces that is in `some name` for example.

This replaces all spaces with comma. How could I match a expression like `*;*;*;` and use sed with the rest of the line and replace spaces with comma?

```
sed -e 's/ /,/g'
```

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, you only want to replace spaces that occur after the final semicolon, correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `gsub()` in `awk` on the last `;`-delimited field:

```
$ awk -F ';' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { gsub(" ", ",", $NF); print }' file
some name;another thing; random;,value,value,value,value,value
```

---

Using `sed` and assuming we'd like to replace all spaces after the last `;` with commas:

```
$ sed 'h;s/.*;//;y/ /,/;x;s/;[^;]*$//;G;s/\n/;/' file
some name;another thing; random;,value,value,value,value,value
```

Annotated `sed` script:

```
h               ; # Duplicate line into hold space
s/.*;//         ; # Delete up to the last ;
y/ /,/          ; # Change space to comma in remaining data
x               ; # Swap pattern and hold spaces
s/;[^;]*$//     ; # Delete from the last ;
G               ; # Append hold space delimited by newline
s/\n/;/         ; # Replace the embedded newline with ;
                ; # (implicit print)
```

The "hold space" is a separate storage buffer that `sed` provides. The "pattern space" is the buffer into which the data is read from the input and to which modifications may be applied.

Comment: Your awk worked perfectly. The sed looks awful :)

Comment: @Starlord `sed` is a neat little language, but can be difficult to decipher, yes. That `sed` code could also probably be made shorter, but it'll do the job.

Answer (score 4):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -F';' -ne '$F[3] =~ s/ /,/g; print join ";", @F'
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and process each line
- `-F` splits each line on the given regular expression into the @F array
- `=~` binds the substitution only to the fourth element of the @F array, i.e. after the element after "random"
- [join](http://p3rl.org/join) joins back the elements of the @F array into the output string

Answer (score 3):

With `GNU sed`

```
$ s='some name;another thing; random; value value value value value'
$ echo "$s" | sed -E ':a s/^(.*random;.*) /\1,/; ta'
some name;another thing; random;,value,value,value,value,value
```

- `:a` label `a`
- `s/^(.*random;.*) /\1,/` here `(.*random;.*)` will capture everything till `random;` in the input line and as many characters as needed till there is a space afterwards, then in the replacement section use backreference to preserve the captured string and change space to comma character

  - note that if there are more than one `random;` in the input, this will preserve spaces only till the first occurrence
- `ta` branch to label `a` if the previous substitution succeeded

Answer (score 3):

```
$ perl -pe 's/ (?=[^;]*$)/,/g' file
```

- Only those spaces that don't see a semicolon all the way to the end of line are selected for substitution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -e'csv(in=>csv(in=>"file",sep=>";",allow_whitespace=>1),sep=>";",quote_space=>0);'
some name;another thing;random;value value value value value
```